# Is it possible to alter the quality of an image using PHP?

Tags: php

Edit: click on the images to see the difference in quality.

**Context**

I'm trying to improve the quality of uploaded images when expanded to 1500px. The images act as a background covering the whole screen when displayed, so I want any image the user uploads, regardless of its original dimensions, to look good when expanded. I looked into code that could change the resolution of the image, but with the code I implemented, it lessened the quality of the photo. For example, the first image I attached below is an image of the photo being displayed normally with its default dimensions (750 x 445). The second photo is how the same file looks after being expanded to 1500px in width and changing its corresponding height, as well (1500 x 890). The quality of the expanded image is worse than the quality of the original image.

**Code**

Here's the code I used to upload the image:

The form:

```
<div class='imgContainer' style='width: 100%; height: 1000px;'>
    <img src='images/collapse.jpg' style='object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
</div>
```

The code that echos the file onto the page after running the `resize_image` function:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    
    if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['type'] == 'image/jpeg') {

        $fileDestination = "images/".$_FILES['image']['name'];
        
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $fileDestination);

        $file = $fileDestination;

        resize_image($file, "1500");

        echo 
        "<div class='imgContainer' style='width: 100%; height: 1000px;'>
            <img src='$file' style='object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
        </div>";

    }

}
```

The function that resizes the image:

```
function resize_image($file, $max_resolution) {

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        
        $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

        //resolution
        $original_width = imagesx($original_image); //get image width
        $original_height = imagesy($original_image); //get image height

        //find ratio of new width to old width and change the height based on the ratio
        $ratio = $max_resolution / $original_width;
        $new_width = $max_resolution;
        $new_height = $original_height * $ratio;

        if ($original_image) { //if image resource exists
            
            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            imagecopyresampled($new_image, $original_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $original_width, $original_height);

            imagejpeg($new_image, $file);

        }

    }

}
```

However, the quality of the image is not maintained as the width of the image increases. In this example, it's not as obvious, but I can tell that the quality of the image is worse. The first image is the original image before being altered (750 x 445) and the second image is the altered image (1500 x 890)

[image: Normal image dimensions - 750x445]
[image: Expanded image dimensions - 1500x890]

**Question**

Is there a way to expand an image after upload without reducing the quality of the photo? Is there something simple I'm missing here? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

**Things I Have Tried**

I also tried adding this code to the `resize_image` function, to no avail:

```
$background = imagecolorallocate($new_image, 0, 0, 0);
imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $background);
```

This code was added in this part of the function:

```
function resize_image($file, $max_resolution) {

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        
        $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

        //resolution
        $original_width = imagesx($original_image); //get image width
        $original_height = imagesy($original_image); //get image height

        //find ratio of new width to old width and change the height based on the ratio
        $ratio = $max_resolution / $original_width;
        $new_width = $max_resolution;
        $new_height = $original_height * $ratio;

        if ($original_image) { //if image resource exists
            
            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    ---->   $background = imagecolorallocate($new_image, 0, 0, 0);
    ---->   imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $background);
            imagecopyresampled($new_image, $original_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $original_width, $original_height);

            imagejpeg($new_image, $file);

        }

    }

}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Think about it - you're asking to create pixels and details where there were none before. That might be possible I guess with highly complex AI image-recognition and rendering software. But not with a some simple PHP functions. Removing detail is much easier then adding it.

Comment: @ADyson that makes sense. With this in mind, do you recommend simply encouraging users to upload images of a certain size so that the image fits well on-screen?

Comment: That's what most websites do, if they care about it. They set a minimum size for the image.

Comment: @ADyson Ok, sounds good. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can easily play with decreasing the quality but not vice versa. There is nothing better than original.

Well there are still some techniques how to enlarge the image step by step aka increasing the size by little steps instead of duplicating the original size while  keeping no compression.

But still you will get worse result in the end.

Note: both images you have shown us has equal quality - just try to zoom the smaller one into the size of the bigger one. They looks both same blurish at the same size.